# UIScrollView now wont remove keyboard iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, keyboard

I have recently started looking into iOS development using Xcode and Objective-C but have hit a little problem (one that is probably quite simple to solve). I have a range of text fields for user input but when the user touched the keyboard there was no way to get rid of it so I added the code in the .m file:

```
[super viewDidLoad];
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textfield {
[textfield resignFirstResponder];
return YES;
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
[self.view endEditing:YES];
[super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

All was fine the keyboard now disappeared when the user touched the screen, except the keyboard was now covering half of the screen and hiding some text fields.
To solve this I added a `UIScrollView` along with the code:

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
_scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
_scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 800);
```

Now the user can scroll through all the textfields however the keyboard wont disappear again when the user touches the screen? Im guessing the problem is something to do with the `UIScrollView` as it worked beforehand?

Anyone know whats going on?

Comment: I answered something like this a while back. This approach will allow you to not have to duplicate the keyboard handling code everywhere.  Also, I use it with scrollviews, so I know it can handle that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17915070/dismiss-the-keyboard-with-multiple-uitextfields/17915121#17915121

Comment: This classes will save you lots of headaches with scrollviews/tableviews and textfields: https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try setting up a UITapGestureRecognizer on the ViewController.View property.

Use that to dismiss the keyboard (EndEditing / ResignFirstResponder / etc.).  Here's a quick example.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // .... your other statements

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestures = [[UITapGestureRecognizer] alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapReceived:)];
    [tapGestures setDelegate:self];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapGestures];
}

-(void)tapReceived:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

Comment: Hey Thank it worked! I added the UITapGestureRecognizer and linked it all up however i have just notice im getting a issue warning in the debug basically saying 

incompatible type 'id<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>

The app runs and works just wondering why its coming up with this?

Comment: Dont worry figured it out needed to add @interface Section1 : UIViewController <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate> to the .h file thank you for the help :)